# How to Override Notification Intents in Exact Target, Android SDK version 4.2.0

Tags: marketing-cloud, actionfunction, android

This example is taken from Journey Builder for Apps SDK Explorer for Android shows a few ways to override notification intents.

> How to Override Notification Intents? The SDK provides three ways to override the default intent opened when someone taps on a push message received by your Android app:
>
> 1. Use the `ETNotifications` class to override the launch intent.
> 2. Launch your own activity to handle the notification tap.
> 3. Specify an action and URI to launch your own activity when the notification receives a tap.

However, The “Journey Builder for Apps SDK Explorer for Android” has been retired. The latest [github link](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/LearningAppAndroid) doesnt display an example.

Can anyone override notification Intents on Exact Target 4.2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct @Venky!  It was recently identified as a shortcoming of the current documentation and will be corrected soon.

In the meantime you can still see all the legacy commits and the overridden examples are still valid:

[Check out the SDKX example in this code commit](https://goo.gl/vDz9Tj)

Comment: Thank you very much "Bill Mote".  it is of great help and will use for my project.